# Microsoft Graph Calendar API All day event's start and end time are not obeying outlook.timezone

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

Unable to get the start and end times for all day events in the preferer outlook.timezone.

I created an all day event for 7th October in GMT+5 time zone. The list and get methods of outlook calendar while using Prefer outlook.timezone is always returning the start and end times in GMT+5.

For example, this is the list method with Prefer = outlook.timezone="America/Los_Angeles":

```
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"IloTFbAhCkiHTVTwnI2TXQABf0dkGw==\"",
            "id": "AQMkADI2ZDFmNDY4LTJlOWItNGVhOS1iM2E1LWZhMzg5ZDQ1MGUwNgBGAAADhQrIuhuED0_HAi76F3pFqAcAIloTFbAhCkiHTVTwnI2TXQAAAgENAAAAIloTFbAhCkiHTVTwnI2TXQABgAeCBwAAAA==",
            "createdDateTime": "2023-10-03T06:47:56.3712403Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-10-03T06:47:57.2702329Z",
            "changeKey": "IloTFbAhCkiHTVTwnI2TXQABf0dkGw==",
            "categories": [],
            "transactionId": 
            "originalStartTimeZone": "UTC",
            "originalEndTimeZone": "UTC",
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2023-10-06T09:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2023-10-06T09:30:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
            },
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"IloTFbAhCkiHTVTwnI2TXQABf93HDQ==\"",
            "id": "AQMkADI2ZDFmNDY4LTJlOWItNGVhOS1iM2E1LWZhMzg5ZDQ1MGUwNgBGAAADhQrIuhuED0_HAi76F3pFqAcAIloTFbAhCkiHTVTwnI2TXQAAAgENAAAAIloTFbAhCkiHTVTwnI2TXQABgJ8E2gAAAA==",
            "createdDateTime": "2023-10-05T13:56:33.1916212Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-10-05T13:56:34.1370576Z",
            "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 420,
            "isReminderOn": 
            "hasAttachments": 
            "subject": "all day event",
            "bodyPreview": "",
            "importance": "normal",
            "sensitivity": "normal",
            "isAllDay": 
            "isCancelled": 
            "isOrganizer": 
            "responseRequested": 
            "seriesMasterId": 
            "showAs": "busy",
            "type": "singleInstance",
            "body": {
                "contentType": "html",
                "content": ""
            },
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2023-10-07T00:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2023-10-08T00:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
            },
        },
]
```

This is the same request using Prefer = outlook.timezone="UTC"

```
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('36e3c7fc-1c36-41a0-9545-fe8480386523')/calendar/calendarView",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"IloTFbAhCkiHTVTwnI2TXQABf0dkGw==\"",
            "id": "AQMkADI2ZDFmNDY4LTJlOWItNGVhOS1iM2E1LWZhMzg5ZDQ1MGUwNgBGAAADhQrIuhuED0_HAi76F3pFqAcAIloTFbAhCkiHTVTwnI2TXQAAAgENAAAAIloTFbAhCkiHTVTwnI2TXQABgAeCBwAAAA==",
            "createdDateTime": "2023-10-03T06:47:56.3712403Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-10-03T06:47:57.2702329Z",
            "changeKey": "IloTFbAhCkiHTVTwnI2TXQABf0dkGw==",
            "categories": [],
            "transactionId": 
            "originalStartTimeZone": "UTC",
            "originalEndTimeZone": "UTC",
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2023-10-06T16:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2023-10-06T16:30:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },

        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"IloTFbAhCkiHTVTwnI2TXQABf93HDQ==\"",
            "id": "AQMkADI2ZDFmNDY4LTJlOWItNGVhOS1iM2E1LWZhMzg5ZDQ1MGUwNgBGAAADhQrIuhuED0_HAi76F3pFqAcAIloTFbAhCkiHTVTwnI2TXQAAAgENAAAAIloTFbAhCkiHTVTwnI2TXQABgJ8E2gAAAA==",
            "createdDateTime": "2023-10-05T13:56:33.1916212Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-10-05T13:56:34.1370576Z",
            "originalStartTimeZone": "UTC",
            "originalEndTimeZone": "UTC",
            "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 420,
            "isReminderOn": 
            "hasAttachments": 
            "subject": "all day event",
            "bodyPreview": "",
            "importance": "normal",
            "sensitivity": "normal",
            "isAllDay": 
            "isCancelled": 
            "isOrganizer": 
            "responseRequested": 
            "seriesMasterId": 
            "showAs": "busy",
            "type": "singleInstance",
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2023-10-07T00:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2023-10-08T00:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
        },
```

In each of the requests, the first event is a normal event. It obeys the Prefer outlook.timezone, but the second event which is an all-day event does not obey the preferred time zone. This is an important bug as I save the event and I don't know in which time zone I am receiving the events. I need to show these events to the users of my application in their time zone.

I tried using different timezones in the prefer header. The normal events timezone was changed but the all day events start and end times did not change

Comment: I believe this is an expected behaviour see https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs-contrib/issues/6459 and https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs-contrib/issues/471

Comment: I don't like this design. I consider an all day event spanning from the start of the day till the beginning of the other day. I can easily store such an event in UTC in my db along with regular events, and no special handling needs to be done when I display these times in any time zone.
For Microsoft's implementation, I need to store all-day events separately, I need to add special handling whenever I am using this. If I am displaying the events to the user, I'll convert the normal events from UTC, but not convert all-day events.